# Can you record calls using Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: phone

I consider it a no-brainer that a smartphone should have a call setting along the lines of "automatically record the last N calls" (deleting the N+1 call record in the process). Unfortunately, that's not the way things work.

Obviously, Android goes to some lengths to prevent users from easily recording phone calls (not sure and don't care about iPhone). There are clumsy workarounds using a headset and similar, but that's 1% of all conversations, basically.

Is call recording something that will simply work on Ubuntu Phone?

Just to be clear, I'm aware there are countries where such call recording is generally illegal, but I don't care about those countries (and even in such countries, call recording is legal under certain circumstances), so making it generally illegal is like making VHS illegal in the '80s to prevent piracy.

Comment: [Ubuntu Touch Internals (Embedded Linux Conference 2014)](http://elinux.org/images/c/cf/Ubuntu_Touch_Internals_1.pdf): page 14 (big diagram) and 17 (Telephony and Connectivity: Ubuntu Touch). [Ubuntu wiki telephony 2010](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DavidSugar/telephony): **oFono Audio Issues**: _The oFono stack does not expose audio to user applications. It seems based on the premise that audio for GSM (or modem devices) would be "switched" into the headphone/mic jacks rather than transported or managed through sources and sinks._ Looks like Android problem. Must continue until the stack is free.

Comment: Thanks, Velkan. Not sure what it means, though. Do you see it as "won't be supported" or "probably won't be supported"?

Comment: I have the same question in http://askubuntu.com/questions/714759/ubuntu-sdk-newbie-with-security-policy-problem-policy-group-debug-not-for-p

Comment: @OsmoAntero Thanks for the heads up and good luck with the app.